# getting compile error for diamond operator in idea ide

Tags: java, intellij-idea, diamond-operator

I am getting this error while trying to compile some simple source code in idea ide.

```
java: diamond operator is not supported in -source 1.6 (use -source 7 or higher to enable diamond operator)
```

jdk is 1.7.40 from oracle

but where is this place to add this "-source 7" option?

i tried adding in ide settings but that had no effect.

Comment: thanks all. yes the language level needs to be upped in project structure.

Comment: duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21006136/intellij-idea-13-uses-java-1-5-despite-setting-to-1-7

Answer (score 28):

You need to set the project language level (default for all modules) **and** the module(s) language level

[image: Project language level]
[image: Module language level]

Comment: this worked for me. Make sure to change at both places. module and project. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Make sure that, in the Project Structure page, you have set your project language level to 7.0.

[image]

After you select this, you will have to reopen your project, but then your diamond operators should compile.

Answer (score 2):

Check Project Structure tab in IDEA, find the followng navigational path

`Project Structure` -> `Project` -> `Project SDK`

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Follow these steps.

```
Right Click on the project------>> go to Open module Settings--->
In that opening window click the Project in project settings---->
and set project SDK
```