# how to support JAVA7 in intellij to use diamands and multi-catch?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

this is very weird.

im using jdk and set my language level to "7.0, Diamonds, ARM, multi-catch etc."

however, when im building my project, it still keeps complaining about:
" error: diamond operator is not supported in -source 1.5
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]"

is there anything else i can try to fix this?
i managed to modify the .idea/misc.xml file to remove jdk-15="true" and it doesnot work.

Comment: Please go into Settings -> Compiler -> Java Compiler and check whether a module specific bytecode version is set there.

Comment: see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21747329/180100)

Comment: i said my language level is 7.0 already, something must wrong with intellij