# How to switch between two JDKs in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android-studio, java-6

Assuming:

My preferred IDEs are Android Studio and Intellij+plugin

I only have access to one work station and that it is impractical to use a virtual environment.

I need to be able to use Java 7 for my other projects

I want my apps to run on Android devices predating 4.0

If possible, how would I ensure that my IDE is compiling code using JDK 1.6 instead of 1.7 if both are present on the machine?

Comment: If you have your minSdk version set to 4.0 or lower, it will automatically compile for java 6 as far as I'm aware.

Comment: @ericbn Android Studio is IntelliJ Idea based, not Eclipse based.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza, you're correct!

Comment: If I have a designated section for assumptions, I probably should have put the IDE preference there.

Comment: Would I need to do anything differently in having two jdks installed on the same machine?

Comment: You might want to see the screenshots I posted as an answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21747254/getting-compile-error-for-diamond-operator-in-idea-ide). This will show you how to choose language level and JDK version (project SDK) for intelliJ.

Comment: Do I even need to install jdk 6?