# Enable lambda expression in Java 8 in Intelij

Tags: java, intellij-idea, lambda

I am trying to follow the [spark java tutorial](https://sparktutorials.github.io/2015/04/02/setting-up-a-spark-project-with-maven.html#intellij).
I set up all things, and tried compiling the project. I got the following error:

```
Error:(8, 34) java: lambda expressions are not supported in -source 1.5
  (use -source 8 or higher to enable lambda expressions)
```

I then tried setting the compiler options and the default JDK, but I am still seeing that error.

Here is how I set my IDE:

[image]

I would be happy if you could help me.

Comment: I already set the project settings to JAVA level 8.

Comment: project and module are to be set correctly.

Comment: Ach, S**T, this i classic one. IDEs just get in your way. I needed to set also the MODULE LEVEL.

Comment: as stated in my linked question answer :p

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's not enough to set the project level. You need to set up the Module level.

> Follow these steps.
>
> ```
> Right Click on the project------>> go to Open module Settings--->
> In that opening window click the Project in project settings---->
> and set project SDK
> ```

See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/21747364/492620

Answer (score 7):

Select project and press `alt+ctrl+shift+s` and you get Project Structure window where you need to set project sdk and language level for project.
[image]

Then you should be able to use lambdas.

Comment: This is exactly what I did with out success. See my screenshot above.