# How to change java source in intellij

Tags: java, maven, intellij-14

I have an intelliJ project which was working just fine untill I accidentally created a maven pom for it by right clicking on the project folder. I'm not sure exactly what the option I clicked was called (it wasn't the one I was trying to click). ctrl-z did nothing, so I deleted the pom. Now I'm stuck with a project that will only compile with java 1.5.

I tried adding the pom again with proprties set as shown in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25888023/how-to-change-java-version-for-maven-in-intellij). I also tried going into Project settings where I can clearly see the Project language level set to SDK default (8).

Answer (score 1):

Go to File -> Project Structure -> Project and choose your desired language version in "Project Language Level" dropdown menu.