# Intellij ignoring Project java source level

Tags: intellij-idea, apache-spark

Note: this is *not* a duplicate. This version of spark requires either jdk 1.7 or 1.8.  The parent pom.xml entry is shown here:

```
   <java.version>1.7</java.version>
```

As shown in the screenshot we have java 1.8 for the SDK and the language level:

[image]

And here are the modules settings:

[image]

But Intellij is just confused about that:

> Error:(73, 51) java: diamond operator is not supported in -source 1.5 
>   (use -source 7 or higher to enable diamond operator)

This is a spark project being built from maven on OS/X.  Intellij Ultimate 14.1.4

[image]

**Update** Here is the pom.xml entry for the jdk

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25888023/how-to-change-java-version-for-maven-in-intellij

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Maven, please watch your pom.xml file. Even if your IntelliJ Project is set to Java 8 your project will compile with the version of Java set in your pom.xml.

Add this to your pom.xml

```
<properties>
  <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
  <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
```

Or directly in the maven plugin :

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source> <!-- java version here -->
                <target>1.8</target> <!-- java version here -->
            </configuration>
 </plugin>
```