# Switch statement is not accepting String variable

Tags: java, string, switch-statement

Can someone please tell me why the switch statement is not recognizing the `gat` String variable.  The `IDE` tells me that a `primitive` is `required` (int, char, short ....), but it found a string.

```
String gat = temp[i];

switch (gat) {
    case "a":
        output[i] = 12 * k;
        break;
    case "b":
        output[i] = 23 * k;
        break;
    case "c":
        output[i] = 34 * k;
        break;
}
```

Comment: Likely Java 6 is used as either the JDK or the target compiler. Pre-java 7 Strings were not allowed in switch statements

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21006136/intellij-idea-13-uses-java-1-5-despite-setting-to-1-7 , this helped me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your project compliance level is set to Java 6 or earlier, you cannot use `String` as case labels before Java 7. But, in the case of your question you might use `charAt(0)`

```
String gat=temp[i];
switch (gat.charAt(0))
{
case 'a':
    output[i] = 12 * k;
    break;
case 'b':
    output[i] = 23 * k;
    break;
case 'c':
    output[i] = 34 * k;
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using NetBeans, make sure you have the latest JDK version.
If you are using Eclipse, have the latest JDK version and set compliance level of the compiler in Java settings to 1.7.